# Autofac contravariance and resolving open generic types

Tags: c#, generics, autofac, contravariance

When resolving all implementations of a generic type (with a contravariant T) from autofac I'd like to get all possible contravariant matches. This only works when registering the *ContravariantRegistrationSource*. But then I get too much instances for open generic implementations because it walks the inheritance tree gives me an instance per subclass.

This might sound a bit abstract, so here's 2 unit tests that demonstrate the problem. They both fail, but I'd like to get at least one of them working:

```
using Autofac;
using FluentAssertions;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xunit;
using Autofac.Features.Variance;

namespace Aiv.Vbr.QueryService.WebApi.Test.AdresMatchTests
{
    public class TestAutofacGenerics
    {
        public interface IGenericInterface<in T> { }
        public class GenericImplementation<T> : IGenericInterface<T> { }
        public class SpecificImplementation : IGenericInterface<TClass> { }
        public class TInterfaceImplementation : IGenericInterface<TInterface> { }
        public interface TInterface { }
        public class TClass : TInterface { }

        [Fact]
        public void AutofacShouldAlsoResolveContravariantImplementations()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<SpecificImplementation>().As<IGenericInterface<TClass>>();
            builder.RegisterType<TInterfaceImplementation>().As<IGenericInterface<TInterface>>();
            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(GenericImplementation<>)).As(typeof(IGenericInterface<>));

            var instances = builder.Build().Resolve<IEnumerable<IGenericInterface<TClass>>>();

            //This fails: only 2 types get resolved: GenericImplementation<TClass> and SpecificImplementation
            //but also expected TInterfaceImplementation
            instances.Should().HaveCount(3);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void AutofacShouldOnlyResolveOpenGenericsForSpecifiedClass()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterSource(new ContravariantRegistrationSource());
            builder.RegisterType<SpecificImplementation>().As<IGenericInterface<TClass>>();
            builder.RegisterType<TInterfaceImplementation>().As<IGenericInterface<TInterface>>();
            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(GenericImplementation<>)).As(typeof(IGenericInterface<>));

            var instances = builder.Build().Resolve<IEnumerable<IGenericInterface<TClass>>>();

            //This fails: 5 types get resolved: GenericImplementation<TClass>, GenericImplementation<Object>, 
            // GenericImplementation<TInterface>, SpecificImplementation and TInteraceImplementation
            //but did not want GenericImplementation<Object> and GenericImplementation<TInterface>
            instances.Should().HaveCount(3);
        }
    }    
}
```

The issue is described [here](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/issues/128) and a possible solution suggested is to use a custom *ContravariantRegistrationSource* which is scoped, but I fail to see how this can resolve my issue.
What can I do?

Comment: `ContravariantRegistrationSource`'s behavior is very weird (I dare to say: wrong). But that said, I would expect `Resolve<IEnumerable<IGenericInterface<TClass>>>()` to result in 2 items, while `Resolve<IEnumerable<IGenericInterface<TInterface>>>()` would resolve in 3 items.

Comment: Happy to accept pull requests if there are improvements folks can pinpoint. [ContravariantRegistrationSource has other challenges, too](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/341) and maybe it can all be fixed up. I don't personally use that feature so I don't hit some of the issues others do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to how `ContravariantRegistrationSource` and `RegisterGeneric` works

When you resolve `GenericImplementation<TClass>`
`ContravariantRegistrationSource` will try to resolve

```
GenericImplementation<TClass>
GenericImplementation<Object>
GenericImplementation<TInterface>
```

because you have

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(GenericImplementation<>))
       .As(typeof(IGenericInterface<>));
```

*Autofac* will returns registration for each of them.

It is the expected behavior and unfortunately there is no easy way to fix it.

I had the same issue with *MediatR* and `INotificationHandler`, I ended by doing my own `IRegistrationSource`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns contravariant registration source without duplicator target. 
/// 
/// <see cref="ContravariantRegistrationSource" /> returns all contravariant implementation of a type. 
/// For example when we resolve IEnumerable&lt;INotificationHandler&lt;SpecificCommand&gt;&gt; it will returns a collection with GenericHandler&lt;SpecificCommand&gt;, GenericHandler&lt;BaseCommand&gt;, SpecificCommandHandler 
/// this registration source will first look up for the native registrations and then group registration based on activator limit type. 
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46464944/autofac-contravariance-and-resolving-open-generic-types </remarks>
public class ExplicitContravariantRegistrationSource : IRegistrationSource
{
    private readonly IRegistrationSource _source = new ContravariantRegistrationSource();
    private readonly Type _type;

    public ExplicitContravariantRegistrationSource(Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));
        }
        if (!type.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Type should be a generic type definition", nameof(type));
        }
        this._type = type;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration> RegistrationsFor(
        Service service,
        Func<Service, IEnumerable<ServiceRegistration>> registrationAccessor)
    {
        if (service is IServiceWithType st
                && st.ServiceType.IsGenericType
                && this._type == st.ServiceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
        {

            // get all non contravariant registration source 
            var originalRegistrations = registrationAccessor(service).ToArray();

            var components = _source
                                // retrieve all contravariant registration source
                                .RegistrationsFor(service, registrationAccessor)
                                // Group will ensure having only a single registration of a activator limit type
                                .GroupBy(this.GetTargetTypeDefinitionOrSelf)
                                // exclude groups if autofac already resolved the same activator limit type
                                .Where(o => !originalRegistrations.Select(oo => this.GetTargetTypeDefinitionOrSelf(oo.Registration)).Contains(o.Key))
                                // taking the last is the default behavior for autofac, it can be improved
                                .Select(o => o.Last());
            return components;
        }
        else
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<IComponentRegistration>();
        }
    }

    private Type GetTargetTypeDefinitionOrSelf(IComponentRegistration componentRegistration)
    {
        return componentRegistration.Target.Activator.LimitType.IsGenericType ?
                    componentRegistration.Target.Activator.LimitType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
                    : componentRegistration.Target.Activator.LimitType;
    }

    public bool IsAdapterForIndividualComponents => _source.IsAdapterForIndividualComponents;
}
```

and I use it like this :

```
builder.RegisterSource(new ExplicitContravariantRegistrationSource(typeof(INotificationHandler<>)));
```